# What is the best control for rendering HTML content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, chromium

My objective is to show the HTML content with style in my WPF application.  I am getting a HTML content as response from a API. I need to show the content in a frame ( preferably textblock).  I tried with webbrowser control of wpf where I faced many issues on formatting over the grid and I am not able to show transparent background for webbrowser control. I found the issue is due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9996233/2819451).

Sample HTML content :

```
<p>My <b>para<b></p><ul> <li>My list1</li> <li>My list2</li></ul>
```

I researched over the internet and found some control for wpf.

[Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/)

[WPF Chromium](http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/)

I am newbie to WPF C# and I don't have idea about how to use the controls in my wpf application.  I tried with some sample application from [here](http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/releases/view/49484) and [here](https://awesomium.codeplex.com/downloads/get/335046).  However, It showing lot  of error due to reference missing.

Also I tried with HtmltoXaml converter and WPF Rich box and found that it skips many of the content after rendering.

It would be really helpful for me if I get a simple sample wpf application working without error implemented with above mentioned controls or links that are useful.

Any new idea to overcome my issue also appreciated.  Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: @Emo I mentioned that in the question. . 
_I tried with webbrowser control of wpf where I faced many issues on formatting over the grid and I am not able to show transparent background for webbrowser control. I found the issue is due to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994933/wpf-c-sharp-webbrowser-scrolls-over-top-menu/9996233#9996233)._

Comment: Sorry @ErnodeWeerd .  I misspelled your name.

Comment: Ha, yes I missed that. Note also that asking for a library or similar advice is off topic on SO. If you rephrase the question to something like: "How do I render HTML transparently across a WPF window?" you might get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a html5 rendering browser, I'd recommend CEFSharp. It's nugettable, stable and is synced with the latest Chromium code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have create a sample app with the help of this [link](http://www.philjeffes.co.uk/wordpress/?p=203). I tried `webView.LoadHtml("<p> paragraph <p>");` instead of `webView.Address = “http://www.google.co.uk”;`
However I am not able to render the content.  Any help.

Comment: That blog post is based on a now rather old CefSharp1 version based on Chromium 25. A good starting point is `CefSharp.MinimalExample` mentioned at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CefSharp_binaries ... after that look at the `CefSharp.Wpf.Example` source for further details. It's mentioned in the README.md of the project GitHub page.

Comment: Related to transparency see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928008/cefsharp-webbrowser-example-in-wpf-transparency/27077798#27077798

Comment: Do try using nuget it helps with the packaging. You've already spotted that you need to be careful with setting the correct x86/x64 for the solution.

Just in case it helps there's a video (that I'm not proud of, but it may help) of me adding CEF. I'll add it here in case it's of use, please excuse the rather poor attempt at presenting http://www.ndcvideos.com/#/app/video/2251 

Finally the CEF FAQ is good. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions

I looked at your web page - have you tried using nuget to add CEF? it sorts out all the libs and dependent files.

Comment: Just checked your code ive spotted 2 problems - 
1 - set the browser sub process path:
 var settings = new CefSettings {BrowserSubprocessPath = "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe"};
2 - set the address/html NOT in your ctor but in the webView.IsBrowserInitialised event (and only after checking the browser is initialised)

In short, CEF is BIG FAT dll which takes a while to load up and initialise...

We will have this working in no time!

Comment: Hi @penderi.  Glad you have find the issue in code without knowing error from my side. I have found there is no webview in [latest Cefsharp version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf/37.0.0) . . however, it is found in the [older version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf/1.25.5). Is there any equivalent for webview in latest CefSharp.  Also, I am able to trigger propertychanged event in older Cefsharp 1.25.5 to find the change on 'isBrowserinitialized'.  But there is no such event in latest Cefsharp 37.0.0. . Any answers for me?

Comment: Ha.  Finally I found the 'IsBrowserInitializedChanged' property. I am running in 64bit machine.  But still I am not able to render the html content with the following code in Cefsharp v 37.0.0.  `webView.LoadHtml("<p>paragraph</p>", "dummy:");`.  
I did a workaround and I am able render html content with following code in Cefsharp v1.25.5 Binaries. `webView.LoadHtml("<p>paragraph</p>")`  But this version has only 32 bit libraries. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm I've certainly rendered successfully with v37. Is your code anywhere??? I'm sure we can help and there's something simple I've failed to mention...